# How to Convert Past, Present and Future UTC datetimes to Local Timezone; Make edits and Convert Back to UTC

Tags: php, datetime, timezone-offset

I am using a third party REST API with PHP cURL that I GET a date field from in the format of (i.e. 2019-03-09T08:00:00Z) which is in the browsers default timezone.
I want to edit this date and PUT it back to the 3rd party server in UTC format.

After putting it to the server the 3rd party GUI will display my date change it my user default timezone which is "America/New York".

I have written a function that works most of the time with the exception of crossing Spring-Forward and Fall-Back dates.
For testing I'm using the following SpringForward and Fall-Back dates in 2019.

**The Official Time Change was March 10, 2019 - Daylight Saving  Time Started**
When local standard time was about to reach
Sunday, March 10, 2019, 2:00:00 am clocks were turned forward 1 hour to 
Sunday, March 10, 2019, 3:00:00 am local daylight time instead

**The Official Time Change will be November 3, 2019 - Daylight Saving  Time Ends**
When local daylight time is about to reach
Sunday, November 3, 2019, 2:00:00 am clocks are turned backward 1 hour to 
Sunday, November 3, 2019, 1:00:00 am local standard time instead.

**Problem(s):**

1. Function detects time change on Spring-Forward at 7:00 AM instead of 2:00 AM
2. Function detects time change on Fall-Back at 6:00 AM instead of 2:00 AM

Can anyone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

**Test PHP Code**

```
    // Create some dates that cross the Spring-Forward that occurred March 10, 2019 at 2:00 AM
    $date_1a = "2019-03-09T01:59:59Z";
    $date_1b = "2019-03-10T02:00:00Z";
    $date_1c = "2019-03-10T06:59:59Z";
    $date_1d = "2019-03-10T07:00:00Z";
    // Create some dates that cross the Fall-Back that will occur on  November 3, 2019 at 2:00 AM
    $date_2a = "2019-11-03T01:59:59Z";
    $date_2b = "2019-11-03T02:00:00Z";
    $date_2c = "2019-11-03T05:59:59Z";
    $date_2d = "2019-11-04T06:00:00Z";

    // Display the original date retrieved from GET
    echo 'Original Date 1a = ' . $date_1a . '<br/>';
    echo 'Original Date 1b = ' . $date_1b . ' - Change not happening at 2:00 AM' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Original Date 1c = ' . $date_1c . '<br/>';
    echo 'Original Date 1d = ' . $date_1d . ' - Change happens at 7:00 AM not 2:00 AM' . '<br/>';

    echo 'Original Date 2a = ' . $date_2a . '<br/>';
    echo 'Original Date 2b = ' . $date_2b . ' - Change not happening at 2:00 AM' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Original Date 2c = ' . $date_2c . '<br/>';
    echo 'Original Date 2d = ' . $date_2d . ' - Change happens at 6:00 AM not 2:00 AM' . '<br/>';

    // Get the timezone offsets based on the dates
    $offset1a = get_timezone_offset($date_1a, 'UTC','America/New_York');
    $offset1b = get_timezone_offset($date_1b, 'UTC','America/New_York');
    $offset1c = get_timezone_offset($date_1c, 'UTC','America/New_York');
    $offset1d = get_timezone_offset($date_1d, 'UTC','America/New_York');

    $offset2a = get_timezone_offset($date_2a, 'UTC','America/New_York');
    $offset2b = get_timezone_offset($date_2b, 'UTC','America/New_York');
    $offset2c = get_timezone_offset($date_2c, 'UTC','America/New_York');
    $offset2d = get_timezone_offset($date_2d, 'UTC','America/New_York');

    // Display the Offsets in seconds
    echo 'Date 1a offset in seconds = ' . $offset1a . ' - 01:59:59 AM' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Date 1b offset in seconds = ' . $offset1b . ' - Change not happening at 2:00 AM should be -14400' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Date 1c offset in seconds = ' . $offset1c . ' - 06:59:59 AM' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Date 1d offset in seconds = ' . $offset1d . ' - Change happens at 7:00 AM not 2:00 AM' . '<br/>';

    echo 'Date 2a offset in seconds = ' . $offset2a . ' - 01:59:59 AM' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Date 2b offset in seconds = ' . $offset2b . ' - Change not happening at 2:00 AM should be -18000' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Date 2c offset in seconds = ' . $offset2c . ' - 05:59:59 AM' . '<br/>';
    echo 'Date 2d offset in seconds = ' . $offset2d . ' - Change happens at 6:00 AM not 2:00 AM' . '<br/>';

    // Convert Adjusted Dates to seconds
    $time1a = strtotime($date_1a)-$offset1a;
    $time1b = strtotime($date_1b)-$offset1b;
    $time1c = strtotime($date_1c)-$offset1c;
    $time1d = strtotime($date_1d)-$offset1d;

    $time2a = strtotime($date_2a)-$offset2a;
    $time2b = strtotime($date_2b)-$offset2b;
    $time2c = strtotime($date_2c)-$offset2c;
    $time2d = strtotime($date_2d)-$offset2d;

    // Create New Date Objects
    $dt1a = new DateTime("@$time1a");
    $dt1b = new DateTime("@$time1b");
    $dt1c = new DateTime("@$time1c");
    $dt1d = new DateTime("@$time1d");

    $dt2a = new DateTime("@$time2a");
    $dt2b = new DateTime("@$time2b");
    $dt2c = new DateTime("@$time2c");
    $dt2d = new DateTime("@$time2d");

    // Format new date objects to UTC for PUT.
    $adjustedDate1a = $dt1a->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $adjustedDate1b = $dt1b->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $adjustedDate1c = $dt1c->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $adjustedDate1d = $dt1d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

    $adjustedDate2a = $dt2a->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $adjustedDate2b = $dt2b->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $adjustedDate2c = $dt2c->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $adjustedDate2d = $dt2d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

    // Display new Date Objects to be PUT
    echo 'Adjusted Date 1a = ' . $adjustedDate1a . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adjusted Date 1b = ' . $adjustedDate1b . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adjusted Date 1c = ' . $adjustedDate1c . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adjusted Date 1d = ' . $adjustedDate1d . '<br/>';

    echo 'Adjusted Date 2a = ' . $adjustedDate2a . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adjusted Date 2b = ' . $adjustedDate2b . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adjusted Date 2c = ' . $adjustedDate2c . '<br/>';
    echo 'Adjusted Date 2d = ' . $adjustedDate2d . '<br/>';

    // This function returns the timezone offset.
    function get_timezone_offset($targetDate, $remote_tz, $origin_tz) {
        $origin_dtz = new DateTimeZone($origin_tz);
        $remote_dtz = new DateTimeZone($remote_tz);
        $origin_dt = new DateTime($targetDate, $origin_dtz);
        $remote_dt = new DateTime($targetDate, $remote_dtz);
        $offset = $origin_dtz->getOffset($origin_dt) - $remote_dtz->getOffset($remote_dt);
        return $offset;
    }
?>
```

**Output of Script**

```
Original Date 1a = 2019-03-09T01:59:59Z
Original Date 1b = 2019-03-10T02:00:00Z - Change not happening at 2:00 AM
Original Date 1c = 2019-03-10T06:59:59Z
Original Date 1d = 2019-03-10T07:00:00Z - Change happens at 7:00 AM not 2:00 AM
Original Date 2a = 2019-11-03T01:59:59Z
Original Date 2b = 2019-11-03T02:00:00Z - Change not happening at 2:00 AM
Original Date 2c = 2019-11-03T05:59:59Z
Original Date 2d = 2019-11-04T06:00:00Z - Change happens at 6:00 AM not 2:00 AM
Date 1a offset in seconds = -18000 - 01:59:59 AM
Date 1b offset in seconds = -18000 - Change not happening at 2:00 AM should be -14400
Date 1c offset in seconds = -18000 - 06:59:59 AM
Date 1d offset in seconds = -14400 - Change happens at 7:00 AM not 2:00 AM
Date 2a offset in seconds = -14400 - 01:59:59 AM
Date 2b offset in seconds = -14400 - Change not happening at 2:00 AM should be -18000
Date 2c offset in seconds = -14400 - 05:59:59 AM
Date 2d offset in seconds = -18000 - Change happens at 6:00 AM not 2:00 AM
Adjusted Date 1a = 2019-03-09T06:59:59Z
Adjusted Date 1b = 2019-03-10T07:00:00Z
Adjusted Date 1c = 2019-03-10T11:59:59Z
Adjusted Date 1d = 2019-03-10T11:00:00Z
Adjusted Date 2a = 2019-11-03T05:59:59Z
Adjusted Date 2b = 2019-11-03T06:00:00Z
Adjusted Date 2c = 2019-11-03T09:59:59Z
Adjusted Date 2d = 2019-11-04T11:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are incorrect because:

- **`Z` means UTC.**  The changes happen at 2:00 AM *local time*, not at 2:00 AM UTC.
- At the start of DST, `America/New_York` goes from `01:59:59-05:00` to `03:00:00-04:00`

  - In UTC that's `06:59:59Z` to `07:00:00Z`  (your 7 AM observation)
- At the end of DST, `America/New_York` goes from `01:59:59-04:00` to `01:00:00-05:00`

  - In UTC that's `05:59:59Z` to `06:00:00Z`  (your 6 AM observation)